# Export Active Directory data from SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Is there any way to extract Active Directory data from SQL Server 2008 R2 in order to restore it on another SQL Server 2008?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you need to transfer logins then I always use [sp_help_revlogin](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918992).